# Gutenberg : how can I get the title of the current block within its 'edit' function?

Tags: block-editor

I'm a Gutenberg newbie.

I'm trying to display a placeholder component with my block's edit function:

```
export default function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes, className } ) {
  return (
    <Placeholder
      icon={ icon }
      label={ title }
    >
  );
}
```

I would like to display the block icon and title, as they have been defined within the function `registerBlockType`.

Could someone point me how to do this ?
Thanks !

Comment: If it's just for a block type you created, then you could, for example, just define a constant with the title/icon/etc. (e.g. `const BLOCK_TITLE = 'Foo Block'`) and simply access the constant from the `edit` function as well as in the root of the `registerBlockType()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wp.blocks.getBlockType()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-blocks/#getBlockType) to get the block type's settings.

So if you've registered a block type with the name `my-guten/foo-block`, just run `getBlockType( 'my-guten/foo-block' )` to get the block type's title, icon, etc.

```js
const { registerBlockType, getBlockType } = wp.blocks;

// Register a block type.
registerBlockType( 'my-guten/foo-block', { ... } );

// Get the block type settings (title, icon, etc.).
const blockType = getBlockType( 'my-guten/foo-block' );

// Inspect the settings:
console.log( blockType );
```

And from within a block type's `edit` function, the block type's name is passed as a property named `name` in the *first* function argument which is an object with other properties like `attributes` and `className`. So for examples:

```js
// Using a Dashicons icon.
registerBlockType( 'my-guten/foo-block', {
    title: 'Foo Block',
    icon: 'heart',
    category: 'common',
    edit: function ( props ) {
        const blockType = getBlockType( props.name );

        console.log( blockType.title ); // Foo Block

        ... your code.
    },
    ... your code.
} );

// Using an SVG icon. (JSX)
registerBlockType( 'my-guten/foo-block', {
    title: 'Foo Block',
    icon: <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" /><path d="M19 13H5v-2h14v2z" /></svg>,
    category: 'common',
    // Unpack the first argument — so that we can use "name" and not props.name.
    edit: function ( { name } ) {
        const blockType = getBlockType( name );

        ... your code.
    },
    ... your code.
} );
```

### Example based on your code

In `edit.js`:

```js
const { getBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { Placeholder } = wp.components;

export default function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes, className, name } ) {
    const blockType = getBlockType( name );

    return (
        <Placeholder
            icon={ blockType.icon.src }
            label={ blockType.title }
        />
    );
}
```

In `index.js`:

```js
import Edit from './edit';

const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;

registerBlockType( 'my-guten/foo-block', {
    edit: Edit,
    ... your code.
} );
```

Comment: got it, thanks ! Can you explain me what's the point of doing `const { getBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const blockType = getBlockType( name );` rather than `const blockType = wp.blocks.getBlockType( name );` ? Just trying to understand it. Thanks !

Comment: The former is particularly useful when you need to call `wp.blocks.getBlockType()` multiple times in the same file, function or block of code, because "getBlockType()" is shorter.. (and easier to type..) so the file/code gets smaller in size.